# Mapping the JSON attribute values dynamically to another JSON and store to Cassandra database

Tags: java, json, cassandra, jsonpath, jsonparser

I am new JSON and Cassandra part i am doing a POC in which i receive a stream of JSON object. I have a configuration JSON which is like the subset of the incoming JSON Object. Right now what i am doing is i have method which will extract the required fields from JSON object and map to a POJO object like below

```
@Table(keyspace = KEYSPACE_NAME, name = DATA_HISTORY_TABLE_NAME, readConsistency = QUORUM,
        writeConsistency = QUORUM,
        caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,
        caseSensitiveTable = false)
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "TRASACTION")
    private double transactionAmount;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date createdDateTime;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private LocalDate createdDate;
}
```

Everything is going good now. I am trying to make this more dynamic way, i have configuration file stored in database which will be pulled through API call during run time. The sample of configuration file structure looks like below and i can have multiple conditions with JSON paths

```
{
    "Condition1": {
        "path": ["JSON PATH OF VALUE I WANT TO FETCH"]
    }
}
```

Sample Condition:

```
{
    "Condition1": {
        "path": ["firstName"]
    },
    "Condition2": {
        "path": ["userID"]
    }
}
```

Incoming JSON can have any values but i want to extract above two values from the incoming JSON object stream and store to Cassandra database. I thought of a solution in which converting the incoming JSON object to a java POJO class and extract the information but since this is a streaming platform this might kill JVM. Please suggest me any efficient way to dynamically map the JSON attributes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a streaming use case, have a look at the [DataStax Apache Kafka Connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaIntro.html).

With the Kafka connector, you can [map the JSON fields to CQL columns](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaMapJson.html). Data from the stream will then get written to Cassandra. Cheers!